# Image downscaling with CSS … Images are blurry in several Browsers

Tags: css, image, firefox, safari

I'm having issues with downscaled IMGs in several browsers… The Images need to be downscaled because they're responsive to the browser size… This is my code:

```
#pic-holder img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /*image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast;*/
    max-width: 70%;
    width:900px;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:1;
```

}

The -moz-transform: rotate (0deg); lets the image get sharper in several versions of firefox. Chrome looks perfect, no problems… But Safari 7 looks very shitty… Does someone have an idea what i could do? Using a JS to change images for Retina Display? That it doesn't have to downscale so much information? I know that downscaling isn't a very smart solution, but what else could I do to have responsive images that get scaled while chaning the browsers width and height?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `image-rendering` property, as seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Syntax:

> - image-rendering: auto
> - image-rendering: crisp-edges
> - image-rendering: pixelated
> - image-rendering: inherit

Here is an example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UNLes/

Like seen in the demo, the first picture is not using the property at all, the second one is **crisp** and the last one should be **pixelated** but this seems not to work.

[image]
(Photo was taken from: http://lorempixel.com/)

The Browser-Support seems to be rather bad, but it should work for current Firefox, Safari and Opera. (Taken from the mozilla docs)

This was the CSS used on the images:

```
/*container for each image*/
div
{
    width: 200px;
}
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
img.sharp
{
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
}
img.pixelated
{
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Yep, -moz-crisp-edges definitely does have an effect, but it's too strong! Mh, is it better to work with A fixed scaling, for example from 1800px to 900px to 450px to avoid the blur?

Comment: @CyrillKuhlmann could you maybe change my jsFiddle demo (just change things, press updated and share the url) to let me see the effect you don't want to see? Maybe place two images: one with dimensions that make the image appear as you want it and one image that is not as crisp.

Comment: I'll try … but I'm not very familiar with jsFiddle yet, sorry …