# Correct way to resize srcset images

Tags: html, image, srcset

What is the correct way to resize srcset images? For example say I have an image that is 2000 x 1337. I resize it to 255 x 170. For 2x srcset should it be:

1. 510 x 340 (based on current image)
2. 510 x 339 (based on original image)

**Edit**

To clarify I want to know how srcset works. For example if I use the 510 x 339 image (technically more correct dimensions based on the original) for 2x will the browser "create" a 510 x 340 container (current dimensions x 2) and then resize the 510 x 339 image to fit inside it?

Comment: from what I know about it should be based on screen size for example

Comment: Based on screen size?

Comment: yes ofcourse only thing that depends is screen size not the actual image

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I did'nt down vote you

Comment: I never said you did, someone downvoted and I'm not sure why. If I have time I am going to do some more tests today to try and understand how browsers handle srcset better.

Comment: your approach should be to find a solution for better image that does not blur with dimension change which is a known web design challenge that and srcset are different issues there is no specific way to set dimension for srcset as such that freedom is given to us a developers/designers .The details of how srcset is handled by a browser is given in my answer and related articles detailing about it is given as reference in it and comments below in my answer .The issue what I am trying to convey is that you are confusing the common web design issue with srcset specific dimension

Comment: You still don't understand my question. I don't want to know how to resize images I want to know if I use the 510 x 339 image (the more accurate size) inside srcset will the browser realise this and adjust or will it stretch it an extra pixel to fill the whole container. Unless you can show me some documentation or tests that prove it one or the other I will keep searching for an answer.

Comment: so you want to know whether image will be strected to fill the container there also a problem will arise see what I am talking about https://jsfiddle.net/f03hwb7p/1/

Comment: and I checked the image on my mobile 291 ppi display but it doesnt make that blurring thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is option 1: 510 x 340 (based on current image)

If you use 510 x 339 (based on original image) the browser will just stretch it until it fits inside the 2x box.

**The image you use must have dimensions divisible by 2 (for 2x) or 3 (for 3x) otherwise the browser will resize it even if you don't have a width or height set.**

---

**Test 1 - 600x300 (3x) image inside 200x200 img container on Chrome, Nexus 5**

`<img src='200x200.png' srcset='600x300.png 3x' width="200" height="200">`

[image: Test 1 - 1]

*This image originally contains a circle, as you can see the browser stretches the image to fill the 200 x 200 container.*

**Test 2 - 600x600 (3x) vs 600x599 (3x) image inside 200x200 img container on Chrome, Nexus 5**

`<img src='200x200.png' srcset='600x600.png 3x' width="200" height="200">
<img src='200x200.png' srcset='600x599.png 3x' width="200" height="200">`

[image: Test 2 - 1]

[image: Test 2 - 2]

*Checking just in case the browser has some smarts to leave images that are 1px different alone (because it is possible that these images would be the "correct" dimensions). Doesn't seem to.*

Answer (score 6):

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="yah">
```

### With srcset, the browser does the work of figuring out which image is best

In the simple example above, all we're doing is telling the browser about some images that we have available and what size they are. The browser then does all the work figuring out which one will be best.

Mat Marquis demonstrated this by showing how the browser approaches it with math. Say you're on a device with a screen width of 320px and is a 1x (non-retina) display. and the images you have are small.jpg (500px wide), medium.jpg (1000px wide), and large.jpg (2000px wide).

The browser goes:

Lemme do some quick math that nobody cares about except me.

```
500 / 320 = 1.5625
1000 / 320 = 3.125
2000 / 320 = 6.25
```

OK, so since I'm a 1x display, 1.5625 is the closest to what I need. It's a little high, but it's the best option compared to those other that are way too high.
Now another browser visits the site. It's also a 320px display but it's a retina (2x) display. That browser does the same math, only then goes:

OK, so since I'm a 2x display, I'm going to throw out that 1.5625 image because it's too low for me and might look bad. I'm going to use the 3.125 image.
See how that's already useful? You're letting the browser do the work of figuring out what's best for it rather than you trying to figure it out

> To what you asked specifically that change in one or two pixel does
>   not matter .What you should be looking at is basically for higher
>   pixel density the large image will be loaded
>
> and for 2X just use double the width 100% percent precision is not
>   required
>   and for getting the width you want you can use the w descriptor:

```
<img src="images/space-needle.jpg"
srcset="images/space-needle.jpg 200w, images/space-needle-2x.jpg 400w,
images/space-needle-hd.jpg 600w">
```

The actual implementation where you’d want a different size image (different height, width) on different screen sizes is accomplished by using sizes attribute along with the w descriptor of srcset attribute. Let’s again learn through a couple of examples:

Example 1
Say you want the image to be viewed in half of the viewport width. You’ll type:

```
<img src="images/space-needle.jpg" sizes="50vw"
srcset="images/space-needle.jpg 200w, images/space-needle-2x.jpg 400w,
images/space-needle-hd.jpg 600w">
```

The browser will now decide which image to download based on the browser width and the device pixel ratio. For example:

If the browser width is 500 CSS pixels, the image will be displayed 250px wide (because of 50vw). Now, this is equivalent to specifying:

```
srcset="images/space-needle.jpg 0.8x, images/space-needle-2x.jpg 1.6x,
images/space-needle-hd.jpg 2.4x"
```

So, for a 1.5x display, images/space-needle-2x.jpg will be downloaded by a browser, since it gives a device-pixel ratio of 1.6x (which is most suitable for a 1.5x display).

**EDIT 1:-**
And what you are actually looking for is rather than srcset.You dont want your images to be blurred in resize or what you call responsive images should maintain its orginal quality and do not blurr.
I have added the Q&A from SO regardiing the same issue here
which explains the use `image-rendering` css property

**EDIT 2:-**

```
img{

      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

The issue regarding image rendering on scaling can be addressed using the image rendering css proprety upto and extant try it out on the scaled image .Documentation is given below.

**On the question whether browser will change the size of image by adjusting the image to fit to the container size answer is ie changing from 539 to 540 :-**

NO it wont srcset depending upon the constraints used only takes the best picture suited for that display wrt pixel density or screen size which ever may be the given contraint.Rest depends upon the css .

Simple example without srcset 
https://jsfiddle.net/f03hwb7p/1/

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-image-rendering
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

[Image downscaling with CSS … Images are blurry in several Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061087/image-downscaling-with-css-images-are-blurry-in-several-browsers)
http://heygrady.com/blog/2012/05/25/responsive-images-without-javascript/

[External Reference 1](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-responsive-images-with-srcset/)

[External Reference 2](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-4-srcset-width-descriptors/)

[Orginal Article from where this paragraph was taken](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)

[W3c examples adn explanation](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-img-srcset)

Comment: I believe this is from an external source. Please be kind enough to reference the URl, If it's not yours. Cheers!

Comment: yes it is I was middle of editing and adding it need to do bit more citation and examples from w3c org

Comment: @JeradRutnam Nice to point it out and sir and do your civic duty :D upvote if find it correct

Comment: I'm appreciate the effort you have put in to your answer but unfortunately I don't think that it answers my question. "To what you asked specifically that change in one or two pixel does not matter" I disagree, 1px can make a lot of difference because the browser might have to resize the image which can create a "blurry" image. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zj1m1q7a/

Comment: that is altogether a different issue the purpose of the srcset is defeated in this process.what you have to do is use photoshop to resize the image according to calculated dimension for each screen size your targeted dimension for 2x,3x,4x etc and use this method to make the image remain sharp and not blurred using photoshop sitepoint.com/resize-an-image-in-photoshop. Once you go for the multiple of the screen size it would adapt the screen size.and another thing for the targeted resize do it each time from orginal file

Comment: and for the part regarding the blurring due to 1pixel its a common issue for not much work around see the following thread to understand what I am talking about https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/scaling-down-images-with-css-makes-them-blurry/.To make it clear actually for srcset is used for different screen size and pixel density different images for it .The issue what you have depend on your image that 1 px or 2 px which you have issue with has to be identified by you and generate resized image for each grid or break point

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49216/how-to-prevent-the-blurring-of-resized-images-png-jpeg-in-illustrator

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-resize-and-make-images-larger-without-losing-quality/

Comment: Giving you the bounty because you put lots of work in, thanks for your time.

Comment: You did answer the question though so you deserve it, I just wanted to put up a concise answer with some tests.

Comment: @joshhunt I am really intrigued by what you are aiming for and what is that you are trying to do with it ?

Comment: Pretty much I had an image with the dimensions in my question and I wanted to see if I could get the more accurate image (510 x 339) to work with srcset. Otherwise I have to stretch the image by 1px, not that big of a deal but annoying to deal with because I am using a script to automatically resize my images.

Comment: Interesting, I just did some more tests and it seems that the image will always be resized unless the image is divisible by 3 (for 3x) or 2 (for 2x) even if you don't set width / height. For example: http://josh18.github.io/

Comment: I am talking about this jsfiddle.net/f03hwb7p/1 if u give it as a src or srcset the default behaviour is for the image to occupy the width it has by default if no size is specified if width is given 100% it will stretch out to occupy 100% of container else it would take up the width the image has by default and leave unused container space empty.If this is not the case then this question has a great importance as this deviates from normal behaviour and it may be useful for people attempting to do the same and yes I checked your image all were 200 width for me

Comment: When I talk about container I am mean the <img> that the image has to fit inside, not an extra div. Sorry for the confusion. My point is that if you have an image set for 3x that is 600x599 the browser will resize it to 600x600 even if you don't have a width / height set on <img>.

Comment: Yes that was the cause of all the confusion .Finally instead of container even if you had used the word "TAG" it would not have caused all this confusion nobody reading this question would not think otherwise of course other than you since you already know what you are asking about and I want ask 1 more thing does this exhibit same behaviour if its 590 or 598 px ?

Comment: Just tested, same behaviour. Tested with 600, 597, 570 (passed) and 599, 598, 590 (failed) so I am pretty sure it has to be divisible by 3 for it to not be resized. (tests were for 3x)

Answer (score 0):

If your image container is fixed to 255 x 170, do the math for

(2x = *2) = (CurrentImageSize * 2 = x)

Ratio is calculating lowest to high (Ascending)

e.g.

```
iPhone: 57 x 57 (1x)   
Retina iPhone: 114 x 114 (2x)    
iPad: 72 x 72 (3x)   
Retina iPad: 144 x 144 (4x)
```

*Technically: if (1x = 57) then (2x = 114)*

Demo Example: https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are trying to say? How do you know that it should be based from the current image size and not the original image size?

Comment: You are using resized images or original image on the site?